# Show $ ( \sin(\theta) - \cos(2\theta))^2 = 1+ \sin(\theta) - \sin(3 \theta) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(2 \theta) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(4 \theta) $

Tags: trigonometry

> Show $ ( \sin(\theta) - \cos(2\theta))^2 = 1+ \sin(\theta) -  \sin(3 \theta) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(2 \theta) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(4 \theta) $

If I would start from the right expression I would be able to reduce it. But I'm not used to do the reverse.

I can see that [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%28sin%28x%29%E2%88%92cos%282x%29%29%5E2) expands the left expression in many ways, one of which is the one I want, but are there any trick to do this expansion by hand?

This question is linked to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983540/how-to-solve-explicitly-the-dirichlet-problem-in-dimension-2-with-boundary-dat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method I. Write everything in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$, and then compare. Tedious, but doable.

Method II. If you know what a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) is, you may determine the coefficients on the right-hand side by integration.

Method III.
First expand the left by $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.
\begin{align}
(\sin x-\cos(2x))^2
&=\sin^2 x+\cos^2(2x)-2\sin x\cos(2x)
\end{align}

Then use the double angle formulas:
$$
\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2},\quad \cos^2(2x)=\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2}
$$
and the general [product to sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities):
$$
\sin x\cos(2x)=\frac12(-\sin(x)+\sin(3x))
$$

Comment: Okay, thank you but I think I was not clear. As in the question linked, I only have the left part of the equaton above. Thanks to other users of this site I have "the answer", but suppose I do not know what is the correct expansion of that expression, how could I get it? May be you can specify more what do you mean with the method 2

Comment: @Gabrielek: Do you understand Method III?

Comment: method 3 is enogh good now. Thank you

Comment: @Gabrielek you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

As we know the RHS, let's  try to express $\cos^2(2\theta)$ in terms of $\cos(4\theta)$

$\begin{align}(\sin\theta-\cos2\theta)^2 & = \sin^2\theta - 2\sin\theta\cos2\theta + \cos^22\theta\\& = \sin^2\theta-2\sin\theta\cos2\theta + \frac{1 + \cos4\theta}2 \end{align}$

Now $\cos2\theta = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta$ we use this to get $4\sin^3\theta$

$\begin{align}(\sin\theta-\cos2\theta)^2 & = \sin^2\theta - 2\sin\theta + 4\sin^3\theta +\frac12+\frac{\cos4\theta}2 \\
&=\sin^2\theta +\sin\theta -( 3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta) +\frac12+\frac{\cos4\theta}2 \\&=\sin\theta - \sin3\theta+\frac{\cos4\theta}2 + 1 - \frac12+\sin^2\theta \\&=\sin\theta-\sin3\theta+\frac{\cos4\theta}2 + 1 - \frac{1-2\sin^2\theta}{2} \\&=\boxed{1+\sin\theta-\sin3\theta+\frac{\cos4\theta}2  - \frac{\cos2\theta}{2} }\end{align}$

Answer (score 3):

We'll use the following identities:

$\cos^2(\theta) = \dfrac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}$

$\sin^2{\theta} = \dfrac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$

$\sin \theta = \dfrac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$

$\cos \theta = \dfrac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}$

$$
(\sin(\theta) - \cos(2\theta))^2 = \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(2\theta) - 2 \sin(\theta) \cdot \cos(2\theta)
$$

$$
\sin(\theta) \cdot \cos(2\theta) = \dfrac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i} \cdot \dfrac{e^{2i\theta} + e^{-2i\theta}}{2} \\
= \dfrac{e^{3i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} - e^{i\theta} - e^{-3i\theta}}{4i} \\
= \dfrac{e^{3i\theta} - e^{-3i\theta}}{4i} - \dfrac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{4i} \\
= \frac1{2} \sin(3\theta) - \frac1{2} \sin(\theta)
$$

As such,
$$
(\sin(\theta) - \cos(2\theta))^2 =  \dfrac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2} +  \dfrac{1+\cos(4\theta)}{2} + \frac1{2} \sin(3\theta) - \frac1{2} \sin(\theta)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the identities
$$\cos4\theta = 2\cos^22\theta -1,\>\>\>\>\>\cos2\theta = 1-2\sin^2\theta $$
$$\sin3\theta =\sin\theta (2\cos2\theta+1)$$
in simplifying the RHS
\begin{align}
RHS=&1+\sin\theta -\sin\theta (2\cos2\theta+1)
-\frac12(1-2\sin^2\theta)+\frac12(2\cos^22\theta-1)\\
=&\sin^2\theta -2\sin\theta\cos2\theta+\cos^22\theta\\
=&(\sin\theta -\cos2\theta)^2=LHS
\end{align}